# /usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file

Tags: android

I am running application which include JNI code, on android phone but CDT build console give output:-

sh bash E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8d\ndk-build all 
/usr/bin/bash: /usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file

Build Finished **

Please help what is this is it error ......

Answer (score 0):

Changed from ENTRYPOINT to CMD.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
CMD ["bash"]
```